# Difference version of this app already installed in OnPrem (SP 2019)

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepoint-2019

I have created an SPFx extension and deployed it to the app catalog in On-Prem (SP 2019). For some of the time, when I install the app to the site it throws an error "Difference version of this app already installed", but I did not install the app to that erroring site. When I installing the same app to different site collection it was installing. I have checked the Recycle bin (Admin, Secondary recycle bin) also. There is no reference to my app on the site. Can anyone please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check via powershell if maybe you will to find the app instance on this site. 
You can do it like this

```
Get-SPAppInstance -Web https://localhost
```

Or using pnp powershell (of course you need to first connect to site before running this command with connet-PnPOnline command)

```
Get-PnPApp -Scope Site
```

I hope this will be of any help. If you will get the app instance then you can remove it Frome site also using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Go to error site collection-> Site Contents, then find the SPFx extension app and remove it. Then remove it in Recycle bin and Second-Stage Recycle Bin.

You can also update the version number in the package-solution.json file, re-package and re-deploy.